# Solving an inequality between 2 functions with 2 variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, fractions, integers

I have the inequality
$$
\frac{p(1-p)}{n} > \frac{(1-n)p^2+(n-2)p+1}{(n+1)^2}
$$
where $p \in [0,1]$ and $n$ can be any positive integer. Using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28p*%281-p%29%29%2Fn%20%3E%20%281%2B%28%28n-2%29*p%29%2B%28%281-n%29*p%5E2%29%29%2F%28%28n%2B1%29%5E2%29) I can see that for $n>0$, we have
$$
\frac{n}{3n+1} < p < 1
$$
however, I cannot seem to get to this conclusion. I currently do the following
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{p(1-p)}{n} &> \frac{(1-n)p^2+(n-2)p+1}{(n+1)^2} \\
p(1-p)(n+1)^2 &> [(1-n)p^2+(n-2)p+1]n \\
0 &> [(1-n)p^2+(n-2)p+1]n - p(1-p)(n+1)^2 \\
0 &> n(1-n)p^2+n(n-2)p+n - (p-p^2)(n^2+2n+1) \\
0 &> (n-n^2)p^2 + (n^2-2n)p + n - n^2p + 2np + 1 - n^2p^2+2np^2+p^2 \\
0 &> np^2 - n^2p^2 + n^2p - 2np + n - n^2p + 2np + 1 - n^2p^2+2np^2+p^2 \\
0 &> np + n + 2np^2 + p^2 \\
0 &> (2n-1)p^2 + np + n
\end{align*}
$$
and I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: You made several arithmetic mistakes in your writeup. E.g. $ - ( p - p^2) (n^2 + 2n+1)$ should be expanded as $-n^2p  - 2np - p + n^2p^2 + 2np^2 + p^2$. You forgot to distribute the negative sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want $p(1-p)(n+1)^2 - n[(1-n)p^2+ (n-2) p  + 1 ] > 0$.

View this as a quadratic in $p$. Expanding and combining terms, we get $$ (3n+1)p^2 - (4n+1) p + n < 0.$$

Factoring, we get $ [ (3n+1) p - n ] [ p - 1 ] < 0$.

Hence $ \frac{n}{3n+1} < p < 1 $.

Comment: Apologies, thought I had marked this answer as the correct answer before. Really, your comment under my post was enough to get me back on the right track though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's $$(n-n^2+n^2+2n+1)p^2+(n^2-2n-n^2-2n-1)p+n<0$$ or
$$(3n+1)p^2-(4n+1)p+n<0.$$
Can you end it now?